# Why can I not limit my Scopus API search by country?

Tags: url, scopus

I am trying to limit my searches on Scopus to articles published in the U.S. only. I keep putting in this facet, but every time I put in the limitation, the search throws an error. For example, I know for sure that there are multiple articles in this pull that have the first author affiliation as the U.S., but when I limit the search to just include U.S. affiliations, it tells me there are no results.

Here is the url I'm using for the search:

```
https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?facets=country(include=United%20States)&field=dc:identifier,authkeywords,affiliation-country&query=issn(19384122)&count=200&date=2018&httpAccept=application/json&apiKey=KEY&insttoken=TOKEN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Putting quotes around "United States" gave me 40 results

```
https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?facets=country(include="United States")&field=dc:identifier,authkeywords,affiliation-country&query=issn(19384122)&count=200&date=2018&httpAccept=application/json&apiKey=KEY&insttoken=TOKEN
```